# Evaluating chess game state using Fairy Stockfish and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, chess

I am using the `ffish` npm library which uses Fairy Stockfish, a version of the Stockfish engine. I am able to create a board

```
let board = new ffish.Board('chess');
```

and set it up via PGN.

```
const game = ffish.readGamePGN(pgn);
const moves = game.mainlineMoves().split(' ');
moves.forEach(move => {
  board.push(move);
});
```

All of this works well, but I want to get the evaluation of the current game state. I am new to chess, so I believe it is also called WDL, but I am not sure. I want to get the evaluation number that is positive if white is expected to win and negative if black is expected to win based on the current game state.

I have looked through the documentation for both ffish and Fairy Stockfish, but I cannot figure out a way to do this. Looking at working examples using Fairy Stockfish, I have seen that you can in fact get this rating somehow, though I cannot find out the way to do it.

Comment: Sounds like a research question, and not a debugging question?

Comment: WDL is most often used in endgame tablebases since in a normal position almost never find win/loss/draw. Evaluation is in general static, that is it takes a gamestate and evaluates it no matter how it got to that position. I am not sure about Fair Stockfish but you should be able to get the eval by something like 'eval = evaluation(gamestate)'